# Retrieve views using Query Service

Tags: web-services, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I would like to retrieve the list of Tables and Views from my Dynamics AX instance, preferably using either the Query or Metadata service.  So far, we've tried the Query service - GetTableNames - but as the methodname implies - it gets the table names.  One would think that there would be a corresponding 'GetViewNames' query, however, there isn't.

Has anyone had any success retrieving the views and tables (names initially, structure secondarily) from Dynamics AX?

I would have tagged this with Query Service, but apparently my points foo just isn't quite there yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the table `SysModelElement` restricted on field `ElementType` = 44.
This will give you the table or view name in the `Name` field.

You should be able to use Query service using a static query, that you define yourself as indicated above.

Comment: Thanks Jan.  So to summarize - the metadata service DOES NOT provide ANY methods to retrieve View names within the AX environment.  

I find this really strange - perhaps my (DB background) view of views isn't consistent with their implementation within AX??

So, if I have a requirement to query data from an AX view, if my view names are static, I should simply use the Query service to query a view?  Or i need to create Queries within AX to then Query using Query service??  **confused**

Comment: The static query I mentioned should address SysModelElement only. Hopes this gets you less confused.

Comment: And yes, you need to make the queries in AX.